# Css code not working in my site

Tags: css, image, hover

I have found the following code here in stackoverflow ([Change text color on image hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34911684/change-text-color-on-image-hover))

```css
img.button:hover ~ p.text {
color: rgb(88, 202, 230);
}

p {
font-weight: 300;
transition: color 1s ease;
}
```

```html
<img class='button' src='//placehold.it/100?text=avatar' />
<p class='text'>Profile</p>
```

And if I try it at http://www.cssdesk.com it works as expected but not in my wordpress site. If I put exactly the same code in one of my post within the HTML tab in the wordpress content then the effect does not work.

Could you tell me why it is working in http://www.cssdesk.com but not in my website?

Comment: Based on your HTML code, it should work. `:)` I am converting your code into a snippet to check it out.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, your code works well. Do you wanna show a place where it doesn't?

Comment: @vitinx you are not doing correctly in wordpress. I think you would be copying the CSS and pasting it in the CSS option in the sidebar?

Comment: knowing wordpress you are getting some code transformation from their editor

Comment: There should be other CSS rules acting on your elements. Check that.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer. You can check the behaviour here: https://www.thetravelerlens.com/sin-categorizar/testhover/ when you hover the image the text "profile" color should change but not :(

Comment: @KuchBhi what you mean with the side bar??

Comment: Hi, @vitinx. Sometimes, you need to specify "!important" for styles that can potentially conflict with other styles happening on the site. Especially for Wordpress sites, where hundreds if not thousands of styles are running at the same time. Try putting "Important" after each style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@vitinx.

Sometimes, you need to specify "!important" for styles that can potentially conflict with other styles happening on the site. Especially for Wordpress sites, where hundreds if not thousands of styles are running at the same time. Try putting "Important" after each style like this:

```
img.button:hover ~ p.text {
color: rgb(88, 202, 230) !important;
}

p {
font-weight: 300 !important;
transition: color 1s ease !important;
}
```

Or, perhaps use JQuery for the hover effect. I wrote this little bit of code, and it can replace the CSS code you have for the blue hover effect:

```
$('img.button').mouseenter(function() {
  $( "p.text" ).css("color","rgb(88, 202, 230)");
});
```

Comment: The solution mainly was this one among others with my theme. They "block" something in the editor and they have told me what to do within my idea so "custom" codes can work

Answer (score 1):

```css
img.button:hover ~ p.text {
color: rgb(88, 202, 230);
}

p {
font-weight: 300;
transition: color 1s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="awr-i">
<style>
img.button:hover ~ p.text {
  color: rgb(88, 202, 230);
}</p>
<p>p {
  font-weight: 300;
  transition: color 1s ease;
}
</style>
 <p>
  <br>
  <img class="button" src="https://www.thetravelerlens.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Distancia-Hiperfocal-cabecera.jpg">
 </p>
 <p class="text">Profile</p>
 <p></p>
 <span id="tve_leads_end_content" style="display: block; visibility: hidden; border: 1px solid transparent;"></span><span class="tve-leads-two-step-trigger tl-2step-trigger-62019" style="display: none;"></span><span class="tve-leads-two-step-trigger tl-2step-trigger-62019" style="display: none;">  </span> 
</div>
```

The

with image inside it prevents sibling selector from working see example, fix is to remove the

wrapping the  in html, or change css but html change seems easiest, so I hope you can do that?:

```css
img.button:hover ~ p.text {
color: rgb(88, 202, 230);
}

p {
font-weight: 300;
transition: color 1s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="awr-i">
<style>
img.button:hover ~ p.text {
  color: rgb(88, 202, 230);
}</p>
<p>p {
  font-weight: 300;
  transition: color 1s ease;
}
</style>
<!--WRAPPING P TAG REMOVED -->
 <br>
 <img class="button" src="https://www.thetravelerlens.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Distancia-Hiperfocal-cabecera.jpg">

 <p class="text">Profile</p>
 <p></p>
 <span id="tve_leads_end_content" style="display: block; visibility: hidden; border: 1px solid transparent;"></span><span class="tve-leads-two-step-trigger tl-2step-trigger-62019" style="display: none;"></span><span class="tve-leads-two-step-trigger tl-2step-trigger-62019" style="display: none;">  </span> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your html file include the following link tag below:

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
</head>
```